# Rounding a decimal without fractions doesn't add fractions

Tags: c#, decimal

I have the following code:

```
var voucherAmountValue = "5";
var totalValue = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(voucherAmountValue), 2);
```

When I write `totalValue` to the console, it prints `5`. I'd expect the fractional digits to be added, printing `5.00` for `totalValue`, but it doesn't: it still prints `5`.

How can I add the fractional digits to a decimal that doesn't have them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `Math.Round` does not *add* fractional digits, it only *limits* them.

Test this:

```
decimal a = 5m;
decimal b = Math.Round(a, 2); // b will be 5
a = 5.00m;
b = Math.Round(a, 3); // b will be 5,00 (not 5,000)
b = Math.Round(a, 2); // b will be 5,00
b = Math.Round(a, 1); // b will be 5,0
```

As you can see, if the original string contains just `"5"`, then the decimal value will also be just `5`, and calling `Math.Round(..., 2);` will only *limit* the fractional digits *down* to 2, it will not add missing fractional zeroes if less than 2.

You can *fix* this by explicitly evaluating an expression that will force the creation of these digits:

```
var totalValue = Math.Round((Convert.ToDecimal(voucherAmountValue) / 100.0m) * 100.0m, 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
var totalValue = ((decimal)voucherAmountValue/100)*100;
```

Comment: Why would that produce anything different? The OP's problem is *formatting* the value, not rounding. Besides, this won't even round the number. If the original number had 5 decimals, the result will still have 5 decimals

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Try it yourself, it does actually work. `((5m/100)*100).ToString()` returns `"5.00"`. (As for your edited comment, yeah, `Math.Round` is still needed to round off excess precision.)

Comment: var voucherAmountValue = 5;
var totalValue = ((decimal)voucherAmountValue/100)*100;
  System.Console.WriteLine(totalValue+""); 
@PanagiotisKanavos: you may try the above code

Comment: Just because some code accidentally produces the result doesn't make it correct, especially when it includes needless operations. A simple `decimal.ToString("N2")` would produce the correct string

Comment: But he's not interested in the string, he's interested in having the decimal value be correct to begin with. `decimal` types behaves differently from `double` and `float` in that they know how many fractional digits they're actually representing. In a `decimal`, `5` and `5.00` is *not* the same value, they may compare equal, and you can certainly format them to a string that would be equal, but the actual value is not.

Comment: This solved my problem var voucherAmountValue = _commandsManager.GetDisplayText();

            var totalValue = (Convert.ToDecimal(voucherAmountValue) / 100) * 100;

Comment: @AlexandruMitu what problem do you think it solved? The number was correct to begin with! Besides, did you try it with a value with many decimals, eg 5.567?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No, it wasn't. Please check the difference between `decimal a = 5.00m;` and `decimal a = 5.0m;`. The two values will know they represent 2 fractional digits and 1 fractional digits. He's converting *from* a string, but he's not asking how to convert *to*  a string, he's asking how to get the right decimal value.

Comment: well.. if you try for 5.678 it would give output as 5.67800 but if you want result as 6.00 (for 5.678)>> var totalValue = ((decimal)Math.Round(voucherAmountValue)/100)*100; will do the trick

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, I do have more code than the one I've provided and it is fine now, I am getting 5.00 instead of 5 on my customer display.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have an integer value. So to round and to have an remainder, try this code:

```
int k = 5;
var totalValue = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(k)).ToString(".00");
```

This second row of code means:

1. integer value `k` converts to float
2. `Round()` method of static class `Math` rounds a value to the nearest integer or to the specified number of fractional digits.
3. ToString(".00") means converting to string type. `.ToString(".00")` means that you will always see if there are nulls. If you do not want to see nulls, use this `.ToString(".##");`

Comment: The input is *text*, not int. If it were, the value wouldn't need rounding. The text must be parsed using the appropriate culture first, then formatted to a string. It probably is something like `1234.567` or `123,456`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "voucherAmountValue will have the value of 5 and totalValue should have the value of 5.00 but it also has the value 5". As I understand OP wants to add nulls after the number.